# Autolayout Causes UIScrollView To Not Work on iPhone 5/5s

Tags: uiscrollview, autolayout

Whenever I launch my app on the iPhone 5/5s the UIScrollview does not work and part of the content is cut off, UNLESS I delete the following constraints:

[image]

However, if I delete these constraints, the content is not correctly aligned on the iPhone 6/6 Plus.

It does however have a little bit of a scroll when I launch it on the iPhone 4s.

How do I fix to have scroll working on iPhone 5/5s/4s but still keep the content the same across every iPhone? thanks

Here is my tree incase
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED: Changed the Vertical Space Constraint constant to 0.